# Implementing Elastic Search Index with Apache Jena Fuseki

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, jena

I want to implement Elastic search for implementing indexing for Jena Fuseki I have followed [document](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/text-query.html) to setup Lucene it worked fine but when I am trying to set Elastic search by updating config ttl file it is not working.

> org.apache.jena.assembler.exceptions.NoSpecificTypeException: has no
> most specific type that is a subclass of ja:Object

When I look at the error I understood elastic search is not part of fuseki installation so I have clone fuseki from git and updated POM file to add elastic search dependency

And used the updated fuseki for index creation but getting below exception

> org.apache.jena.shared.JenaException:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.client

I have also tried to load elastic search using ttl file loader but still not working

> [] ja:loadClass       "org.elasticsearch" .

Can someone please help me on how I can implement Elastic search indexing for Fuseki using assembler configuration file?

Comment: The ElasticSearch code needs to be added. It isn't included in Fuseki as distributed (ES and all it's dependencies are quite big). You'll need to set up your own packaging - one way is to take the POM for the Fuseki module that builds the form you are using (jena-fuseki-war, jena-fuseki-fulljar or jena-fuseki-server), change the artifact name and add jena-text-es as a dependency. Example in https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-fuseki2/jena-fuseki-fulljar/pom.xml (may need adjusting).

Comment: I have updated the POM file and added jena-text-es dependency but getting error while building index using config.ttl file "indexES with type: http://jena.apache.org/text#TextIndexES assembler class: class org.apache.jena.query.text.es.assembler.TextIndexESAssembler
    root: http://localhost/jena_example/#text_dataset with type: http://jena.apache.org/text#TextDataset assembler class: class org.apache.jena.query.text.assembler.TextDatasetAssembler"

Comment: (1) What's the configuration file look like (2) that looks like only part of an error message. Maybe easier to email users@jena.apache.org with a complete, minimal example.

Comment: I have mailed my issue with sample files to users@jena.apache.org

Comment: The error is the stacktrace showed that the ES server wasn't contactable.

Comment: Yes there was some issue in elastic search cluster setup after resolving that I am able to build Elastic Search index